# Berlin public transport apps (similar to jakdojade)

Tags: public-transport, berlin, mobile-apps

Is there some APP similar to [jakdojade](http://torun.jakdojade.pl/) to search for public transport in Berlin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Berlin transport authority, the BVG, has an app for that for both iOS and Android. You can search timetables, find routes and use the phone as a ticket.

They have links on their [website](http://www.bvg.de/en/Tickets/Other-ways-to-buy/Mobile)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. I've just installed it from the QR code. Now I have to learn how to read the data.

Comment: @Sigur glad I could help :) I found Berlin generally easy to navigate, shouldn't be too hard to figure out

Comment: I installed that app since I will have long transit in berlin soon. it seems a good and easy to use app..

Answer (score 4):

The Android App [Öffi](http://offi.schildbach.de/) is really helpful to navigate public transport all around the german speaking countries in central europe.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the BVG app mentioned in the other answer is [Citymapper](https://citymapper.com/berlin), which has a nicer interface.  Google Maps also gives decent public transit directions.

Comment: Just be aware that last time I checked Citymapper uses average intervals and not real timetables. Especially for services leaving less than 15 minutes their connections are often suboptimal.

Comment: Very easy to use and ready the information from this app. Thanks so much.